# Select same field on 2 table with same alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose this:

**users**

```
id | name | address
```

**partners**

```
id | name | company | address
```

Even though the tables are distinct sometimes happens having to associate the users or partners id to the same function ..

For example, the access table

**acl**

```
uri | uid | group | operations
```

Here "uid" can be both user and partner.

How can I read the data of 2 tables with the same alias?
something like:

```
$selectQuery = <<<QUERY
SELECT A. *, 
       U.name P.name AS username, 
       G.name AS groupname 
FROM [acl] A
LEFT JOIN [users]   U ON A.uid = U.id
LEFT JOIN [partner] P ON A.uid = P.id
LEFT JOIN [groups]  G ON A.gid = G.id
WHERE A.id =: id 
LIMIT 0.1
QUERY;
```

Comment: only users can access the table. simple

Comment: ?? users and partners can access the table

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `COALESCE` or `IFNULL`

```
IFNULL(U.name, P.name) AS username, 
COALESCE(U.name, P.name) AS username,
```

Both of those will do the exact same thing in this situation. If `U.name` is not `NULL` then `username` will be `U.name`, otherwise it'll be `P.name`.

Comment: Actually I'm no longer sure if this is what you want. For each `A.uid` is there both a corresponding user and a partner? Or is there either 1 or the other. This answer assumes you there will be either a partner or a user. Otherwise you want `UNION ALL`

Comment: "For each A.uid is there both a corresponding user and a partner?" No, there is either 1 or the other.

Comment: Then both of these should work. Just change `U.name P.name AS username, ` in your query above to `IFNULL(U.name, P.name) AS username, `

Comment: I decided to divide the tables, first I got 1 table for both users and partners but during the uml analisys I decided to split the table and separate users from partners..

Comment: That probably makes the most sense

Answer (score 0):

USE UNION ALL with the condition......it should help hopefully

Comment: Maybe you can give the complete query?